# Synchronize value (counter) across goroutines

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have a golang application that goes through pages of a website, and is supposed to download every link on the website. It looks something a little like this (I don't know the number of pages beforehand, so that is done synchronously):

```golang
page := 0
results := getPage(page)
c := make(chan *http.Response)
for len(results) > 0 {
  for result := range results {
    go myProxySwitcher.downloadChan(result.URL, c)
    fmt.Println(myProxySwitcher.counter)
  }
  page++
  results = getPage(page)
  myProxySwitcher.counter++
}
```

The twist is, every 10 requests, I want to change the Proxy I use to connect to the website. To do this, I made a struct with a counter member:

```golang
type ProxySwitcher struct {
    proxies []string
    client  *http.Client
    counter int
}
```

And then I have incremented the counter each time a request is made from `downloadChan`.

```golang
func (p *ProxySwitcher) downloadChan(url string, c chan *http.Response) {
    p.counter++
    proxy := p.proxies[int(p.counter/10)%len(p.proxies]
    res := p.client.Get(url, proxy)
    c <- res

}
```

When it does the downloads, it doesn't appear the the counter is synchronized between goroutines. **How can I sync the value of the counter between goroutines?**

The result I get from those printlns are:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
```

And I am expecting

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

Comment: You've created a race condition. You need to synchronize access with a mutex or `sync/atomic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code.

In the first snippet, you're modifying the `counter` field from the "main" goroutine:

```golang
  // ...
  myProxySwitcher.counter++
```

In the third snippet, you're also modifying that counter from a different goroutine:

```golang
  // ...
  p.counter++
```

This is illegal code in Go. By definition, the results are undefined. To understand why, you'll have to go over the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem). Hint: it won't likely be an easy read.

To fix it, you need to ensure synchronization. There are many ways to do it.

One way, as suggested in a comment on your question, to do it is to use a mutex. Below is an example, kinda messy, as it would need some refactoring on the main loop. But this is how you would synchronize access to the counter:

```golang
type ProxySwitcher struct {
  proxies []string
  client  *http.Client
    
  mu sync.Mutex
  counter int
}

func (p *ProxySwitcher) downloadChan(url string, c chan *http.Response) {
  p.mu.Lock()
  p.counter++
  // gotta read it from p while holding
  // the lock to use it below
  counter := p.counter
  p.mu.Unlock()

  // here you use counter rather than p.counter,
  // since you don't hold the lock anymore
  proxy := p.proxies[int(counter/10)%len(p.proxies)]
  res := p.client.Get(url, proxy)
  c <- res
}

// ... the loop ...
for len(results) > 0 {
  for result := range results {
    go myProxySwitcher.downloadChan(result.URL, c)
    
    // this is kinda messy, would need some heavier
    // refactoring, but this should fix the race:
    myProxySwitcher.mu.Lock()
    fmt.Println(myProxySwitcher.counter)
    myProxySwitcher.mu.Unlock()
  }
  page++
  results = getPage(page)

  // same... it's messy, needs refactoring
  myProxySwitcher.mu.Lock()
  myProxySwitcher.counter++
  myProxySwitcher.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Alternatively, you could change that counter to e.g. `uint64`, and then use the `atomic/sync` package to perform goroutine-safe operations:

```golang
type ProxySwitcher struct {
  proxies []string
  client  *http.Client
  counter uint64
}
func (p *ProxySwitcher) downloadChan(url string, c chan *http.Response) {
  counter := atomic.AddUint64(&p.counter, 1)

  // here you use counter rather than p.counter, since that's your local copy
  proxy := p.proxies[int(counter/10)%len(p.proxies)]
  res := p.client.Get(url, proxy)
  c <- res
}

// ... the loop ...
for len(results) > 0 {
  for result := range results {
    go myProxySwitcher.downloadChan(result.URL, c)
    counter := atomic.LoadUint64(&myProxySwitcher.counter)
    fmt.Println(counter)
  }
  page++
  results = getPage(page)

  atomic.AddUint64(&myProxySwitcher.counter, 1)
}
```

I'd probably use this last version, as it's cleaner and we don't really need a mutex.